# Replacing Strings at specific locations

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

```
text = {"Donc", "j'obtiens", "<i>aᵢ₁(\[Alpha]₁ - \[Beta]₁) + aᵢ₂(\[Alpha]₂ - \
\[Beta]₂) + ... + aₙ₁(\[Alpha]ₙ - \[Beta]ₙ) = bᵢ - bᵢ = 0.</i>", \
"<i>aᵢ₁(\[Alpha]₁ - \[Beta]₁) + aᵢ₂(\[Alpha]₂ - \[Beta]₂) + ... + \
aₙ₁(\[Alpha]ₙ - \[Beta]ₙ) = bᵢ - bᵢ = 0.</i>", "Donc en particulier", \
"ça veut dire que si je multiplie par <i>c</i>", "pour tout nombre réel \
<i>c</i>"}
```

Now my question is:

1. How can I get the position of in the list of every object that starts with `<i>`?
2. How can I replace the `<i>` at the start of that object and the `</i>` at the end of that object by another string ?

By "object" I really mean a list object: for instance, I don't want the `<i>` and `</i>` to be replaced in "ça veut dire que si je multiplie par `<i>c</i>`", since this object of the list does not start with an `<i>`.

EDIT: To clear any confusion, here is how the text could look like afterwards:

```
"Donc", "j'obtiens", "REPLACE(\[Alpha]₁ - \[Beta]₁) + aᵢ₂(\[Alpha]₂ - \
    \[Beta]₂) + ... + aₙ₁(\[Alpha]ₙ - \[Beta]ₙ) = bᵢ - bᵢ = 0.REPLACE", \
    "REPLACEaᵢ₁(\[Alpha]₁ - \[Beta]₁) + aᵢ₂(\[Alpha]₂ - \[Beta]₂) + ... + \
    aₙ₁(\[Alpha]ₙ - \[Beta]ₙ) = bᵢ - bᵢ = 0.REPLACE", "Donc en particulier", \
    "ça veut dire que si je multiplie par <i>c</i>", "pour tout nombre réel \
    <i>c</i>"
```

Comment: Could try something like `Position[text, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "<i>*</i>"]]`, but that won't catch the last two items with italics tags since they don't actually "start with `<i>`", as the criterion you mentioned.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less That's actually perfect ! Maybe I was not clear enough, but I don't want to catch "<i>" where the sentence does not start with "<i>". Can you post it as an answer ? Then I can accept it, if you also know how to replace the "<i>" and "</i>" in the found sentences.

Comment: If just for replacement, it seems no need to get their positions.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Okay, interesting. How would you do it then ?

Comment: You did not mention what kind of replacement you wanted to do. Is it derived from the matching string, or something completely different?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less True. I want to simply replace it with another string.

Comment: A slight modification of @Αλέξ's answer should do; just change the second part of his replacement rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Cases[text, _String?(StringMatchQ["<i>*"]), Infinity]
```

> {"*aᵢ₁(α₁ - β₁) + aᵢ₂(α₂ - β₂) + ... + aₙ₁(αₙ - βₙ) = bᵢ - bᵢ = 0.*", "*aᵢ₁(α₁ - β₁) + aᵢ₂(α₂ - β₂) + ... + aₙ₁(αₙ - βₙ) = bᵢ - bᵢ = 0.*"}

```
StringReplace[text, 
 StartOfString ~~ "<i>" ~~ s__ ~~ "</i>" ~~ EndOfString :>  "REPLACE" <> s <> "REPLACE"]
```

> {"Donc", "j'obtiens", "REPLACEaᵢ₁(α₁ - β₁) + 
>   aᵢ₂(α₂ - β₂) + ... + aₙ₁(αₙ - βₙ) = bᵢ - bᵢ 
>   = 0.REPLACE", "REPLACEaᵢ₁(α₁ - β₁) + aᵢ₂(α₂ - 
>   β₂) + ... + aₙ₁(αₙ - βₙ) = bᵢ - bᵢ = 0.REPLACE", 
>   "Donc en particulier", "ça veut dire que si je multiplie par 
>   *c*", "pour tout nombre réel *c*"}

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works nicely and is comprehensible.

Answer (score 4):

For replacement, (e.g., below is just to delete them)

```
StringReplace[text, RegularExpression["^<i>(.*)</i>$"] -> "$1"]
```

The key point is to locate the (sub)strings (but not by knowing the positions explicitly), having achieved which, one can do whatever one wants to them :).

---

For the updated detailed request

```
StringReplace[text, RegularExpression["^<i>(.*)</i>$"] -> "REPLACE$1REPLACE"]
```

Comment: This replaces the "<i>" and "<i/>" but kills the rest of the text.

Comment: @james `StringReplace` is better here, which leaves strings unmatched untouched. I modified it.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringReplace["this is the <i>old text</i>" , 
 "<i>" ~~ ___ ~~ "</i>" -> "new text"]
```

Comment: This replaces everything in between "<i>" and "<i/>". Please have a look at my example in the question.

Comment: That's what I was asking you about earlier @james. So, what you want is a derived string and not an independent string. That's because replacing `<i>stuff</i>` with `stuff` and replacing `<i>stuff</i>` with `something` needs different approaches.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less I see. I guess I miscommunicated my answer.  Thank you for the information.